# How to take html input and use it in views.py?

Tags: python, html, django

I checked documentation and stack, but still can't make it. I want button from html to grab input data and inject to views.py as a city and make rest of the code which works when I hardcode city variable. And It shouldn't be made on new url. Thanks for help!
html:

```
<form method="POST "action="{% url 'weather' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city"><br> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Get my weather</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


def scrape_weather(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        old_weather = Weather.objects.all()
        old_weather.delete()
        api_adress = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="
        api_key = "&appid=3a99cf24b53d85f4afad6cafe99d3a34"
        city = request.POST.get("city")

        url = api_adress + city + api_key

        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        new_weather = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
        degree_kelvin = int(json_data['main']['temp'])
        degree = degree_kelvin-273
        pressure = json_data['main']['pressure']      

        new_weather = Weather()
        new_weather.degree = degree
        new_weather.pressure = pressure

        new_weather.weather = new_weather
        new_weather.save()

    return render(request, "news/home.html")
```

urls.py:

```
path('weather/', scrape_weather, name='weather'),
```

Comment: so what isn't working about this code?

Comment: When i click button my url changes to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/weather/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=yILVTtRsk73pGy2k5FQehUeH2gNjlq2dWGGJzEVreFilEaLfzZ5LdoNUBDbB9E4K&city=warsaw" and nothing else happens

Comment: Are you sure your form in the html has `method="POST"`? That looks like it's doing a `GET` request (which is the default). I just noticed you actually have `method="POST "` with an additional space on the end, I'm not sure how tolerant HTML is of things like that but this could be what's causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, It works now, but still redirects me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well it should redirect you, to `/weather/` - that's what you've told it to do

Comment: Yes, because it's assigned to my function in views. Can you give me any hint how to make it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do, and what isn't working. But if your original question has been answered, I suggest you ask the new one in a new question. (And I will vote to close this question as a typo, if the original issue was just the extra space in the `method` attribute.)